# C# & SQL - Followed examples to write a Parallel.ForEach loop to create threads, but it is throwing exceptions about the connection state

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parallel-processing

I have tried the code below and it throws exceptions saying that the query requires an open connection, and that the current state is open/opening/closed.

It is a `Parallel.ForEach` loop creating threads, and I want them to open the connection to the SQL Server database and insert something there. I followed the patterns to handle parallelism in other questions here, but they don't work for me.

Can someone throw some light on this this? How to make this happen?

Connection open error?

[image: Connection open error?]

Connection closed error

[image: Connection closed error]

```
private static void CreateResultTable()
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(_fakeTableFileFull, tableRow =>
        {
            var fileRow = Regex.Split(tableRow, PatternExFile);
            SearchForConfirm(fileRow[3], fileRow[1], fileRow[2]);
        });
    }

    private static void SearchForConfirm(string id, string number, string date)
    {
        if (tokenChecksum.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            WriteLineToResultFile(number, date, tokenChecksum[id], id);
        }
    }

    private static void WriteLineToResultFile(string number, string date, string confirm, string id)
    {
        using (Conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"]
            .ConnectionString)) 
        {
            Conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[PanChecksums] " +
                                                     "([number], " +
                                                     "[Id]) " +
                                                     "VALUES " +
                                                     "(" + Int64.Parse(id) +
                                                     "," + "'" + confirm + "'" + ")", Conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }

        using (Conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"]
            .ConnectionString))
        {
            Conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT IdNumber ON;", Conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[IdNumber] " +
                             "([Id], " +
                             "[number], " +
                             "[Month], " +
                             "[Year]) " +
                             "VALUES " +
                             "(" + "'" + id + "'" + "," +
                             Int64.Parse(number) + "," +
                             "'" + date.Substring(0, 2) + "'" + "," +
                             "'" + date.Substring(2, 2) + "'" + ")", Conn);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd = new SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT IdNumber ON;", Conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: Put your actual code in the post not just in pictures.

Comment: Parallel.ForEach is designed to do heavy CPU work. In your case you need to simply wait for IO of SQL server, no CPU work. Better to use manualy created tasks and wait for them to finish. Or you can just specify parallelism option to say 4 or something.

Comment: as per the error on connection open. I suppose your application can't find any sql connection available.

Comment: don't forget to open the connection after creating it. and don't forget to only close it when whole foreach loop is done.

Comment: You've not shown us but I'm *guessing* that `Conn` is a *field* in this class and so all of your parallel threads are over-writing the variable with what *should* be something only held locally.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever - You are right! It was a field. Now held locally and working better.

Comment: To maximize throughput for database inserts, consider SqlBulkCopy or passing many rows in a single request using a table-valued parameter. These methods often outperforms singleton inserts by orders of magnitude. With the parallel insert method, at least parameterize the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Parallel.ForEach(list, x=> {...});
```

Use light weight tasks from ThreadPool:

```
var tasks = list.Select(x=> Task.Run(()=> {...})).ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Parallel.ForEach is used for heavy CPU load, not for IO load (which is cause of your error, you simply exhaust SQL connection pool). Another approach is to set DegreeOfParallelism:

```
Parallel.ForEach(list, new ParallelOptions(){ MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, x => {...});
```

It will limit connection creation to 4 at the time, but I don't recomend it because you will need manualy manage ALL of your Parallel.ForEach invokations, which can become quite a pain.

Also, your connection is opened twice in row, in one iteration, which is strange. Simply open one connection and use it across all iterations. It will require from you to pass this dependency in every function which need connection, but it is common practice.

Comment: I would like to use tasks from ThreadPool but I am not very familiar with how that works, so I took the MaxDegreeOfParallelism suggestion on the loop instead. So it can only have a limited number of threads running at a time.I guess that should be fine!

Comment: ThreadPool manages count of its threads and share this fixed ammount of threads across entire application. So, in other words, every call to it will be performed in some of this threads. It is convinient to use them, instead of degree of parallelism, where you don't need CPU, and just want to, for example, send a ton of images to some host, or execute a bunch of SQL statements on some machine, in other words - async IO operations which not depend on CPU at all, but on some Input/Output operations.

Answer (score 0):

Your connections should be open:

```
Conn.Open();
```

only close it when the Parralel.ForEach is done.

A better solution wouldbe to merge multiple insert together into 1 insert:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2)
VALUES 
  ('',''), -- first insert row
  ('','')  -- second insert row
```

Just join multiple inserts together with a comma.